# Android - Display a button and text simultaneously

Tags: android, eclipse, button, text

I have spent several hours on this, and I have made very little to no progress.  I have asked a similar question, but over a 2 hour period, still have not succeeded.  So I will ask this and be as specific as I can.  I have put about three hours into this, so please do not write me off.

I want to simultaneously display text and a ToggleButton.  I can display one or the other, but not both.  Please help!  Here is my code:

```
public class Counter extends Activity {

    private int count = 5000;
    private int hiCount = 0;
    private boolean capCount = false;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle instCounter) {

        super.onCreate(instCounter);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_counter);

        TextView tv = new TextView(this);

        tv.setTextSize(250);
        if (count < 10000 && capCount == false) {

            tv.setText(Integer.toString(count));
        } else {
            capCount = true;
            if (count >= 10000) {
                hiCount += 10;
                count -= 10000;
            }
            if (hiCount < 100) {

                tv.setText(hiCount + "k+" + count);
            } else {
                tv.setText("Over\n100k");
            }
        }
        tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        setContentView(tv);

//      ToggleButton btnPause = new ToggleButton(this);

//       if (btnPause == buttonOn) {
//       Intent pause = new Intent(this, Pause.class);
//       startActivity(pause);
//       }

    }

    public void pauseCounter(View view) {
        Intent pause = new Intent(this, Pause.class);
        startActivity(pause);
    }

    // // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    // getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

---

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Counter" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="ToggleButton" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the Activity to use the TextView as the **whole** view. Your button will never show like this(and neither really, will anything else you have in your layout)! In your `R.layout.activity_counter` make a TextView and Button, and use

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView1);
```

This will allow you to have **both** UI elements as you are finding the TextView from your layout then working with it while leaving everything else alone.

Comment: Thanks.  Where in R.layout.activity_counter should I put it?

Comment: Based on your xml, it seems fine how it is. If Eclipse's graphical layout viewer isn't complaining and it shows your layout as you want it, it's usually fine to run.

Comment: It's not fine though.  I can display the button or the text field. But not both at once, which is what I need.

Comment: What do you mean? If you're calling findViewById and taking out `setContentView(tv);` you should be fine. Maybe you need to mess with the layout orientations, but your problem was setting the content view to that of your new TextView.

Comment: If I get rid of setContentView(tv), then it no longer displays the text I want.

Comment: Glad you have figure it out.

Comment: No problem! Next time you have a problem, try verbally going through your code. I've caught many errors by doing that.

Answer (score 0):

just change `onCreate` like

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle instCounter) {

    super.onCreate(instCounter);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_counter);

    TextView tv = (TextView)(findViewById(R.id.textView1));

    tv.setTextSize(250);
    if (count < 10000 && capCount == false) {

        tv.setText(Integer.toString(count));
    } else {
        capCount = true;
        if (count >= 10000) {
            hiCount += 10;
            count -= 10000;
        }
        if (hiCount < 100) {

            tv.setText(hiCount + "k+" + count);
        } else {
            tv.setText("Over\n100k");
        }
    }
    //tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    //setContentView(tv);

     ToggleButton btnPause = (ToggleButton)(findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1));

     if (btnPause == buttonOn) { //Do not know what you want here
     Intent pause = new Intent(this, Pause.class);
     startActivity(pause);
     }

}
```

Comment: Both of those changes just come up red.